# Empty String has "\u0000" at the end

Tags: java, android, string, ascii, trim

I get String response from server, which should be 1 space. Value is shown below:

[image]

I have used `trim()`, `TextUtils.isEmpty()` on Android but String description still looks not empty. I have checked if it is equals to "" or " ", but it is not. **How do i check this special String ?**

I have tried to replace `\u0000`chars at the end of string, looks not working too.

Comment: Have you tried `description = description.replaceAll("\\s+", "");` ?

Comment: @Shark seems this worked, why?

Comment: `\u0000` is just the null-terminator, it should get removed by either `.trim()` or the `whitespace regex i proposed`

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov it worked because i'm good at what I do :) i'll write you an answer and explain a bit, gimme a sec.

Comment: @Shark still misses some cases, but i have also used trim() before, check?

Comment: Oh wait, try your example again, just use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` :)

Comment: That `160` is a hard (aka [non-breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space)) space. You don't mention this at all, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
```

what this does is, go thru the entire string, and remove all whitespace characters which include `{ ' ', '\r', '\t', '\n' ...}`

It doesn't guarantee to remove **ALL** off them in all encodings/charsets, but it usually gets the (bigger part of) job done. If there are more special/missing cases, please write them down and we'll treat them as exceptions which they are instead of lump them in 'catch-all' solution.

This solution will just remove all whitespaces and spaces from the string. Do try `trim()`ming and this and see how close that gets you to the desired end-result.

Comment: What does `trim()` do then, shouldn't it delete whitespace too? But it does not in this case

Comment: No, `trim()` removes whitespaces **FROM START AND FINISH** meaning, whitespaces before the first character and whitespaces after the last character. so `"   11 22 33 4  "` becomes `"11 22 33 4"`

EDIT: atually, `trim()` just removes the codepoints - `\u0020` :)

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov char 160 is not a whitespace, but a non breaking space

Answer (score 1):

Char 160 is `NO-BREAK SPACE` in `UTF-8` character-set. The `string` you received is not empty but contains a valid character.

The first thing before you consider this as empty `string` is to check what the server is trying to inform you about.

If you still want to remove it, then apart from replacing `\u0000` also `replace` this character.

something like this would do:

```
description = description.replace(new String(new char[] {160}), "");
```

Comment: This works too, so if i had 32 instead of 160 following with \u0000 null terminator, `trim()`would work right?